# angularjs Insert new row in table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

// dynamic table, with insert row and delete. but when i insert row, if firs row have some information when i create new row the values are tranfered, when i want an empty new row, someone can help?

// table creation

```
     <html>
  <head>
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      table, th , td {
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      padding: 5px;
      }
      table tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      }
      table tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app = "mainApp" ng-controller = "studentController">
      <td>
        <table id="Pessoas">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>delete</th>
          </tr>
          <tr >
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox"/></td>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" /></td>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
            <input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add" onclick="insRow()"/>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script>

    // script to delete row
    function deleteRow(row) {
        var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById('Pessoas').deleteRow(i);

    }

    // script to insert new row
    function insRow() {
        var x = document.getElementById('Pessoas');
        var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);

        x.appendChild(new_row);
    }

    //Data 
    var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

    mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
        $scope.student = {

            subjects: [{
                name: 'Diogo',
                age: 70,
                email: 'aaaa@aaa.com'
            }, {
                name: 'Joao',
                age: 80,
                email: 'aaaa@aaa.com'
            }, {
                name: 'maria',
                age: 65,
                email: 'aaaa@aaa.com'
            }, {
                name: 'Rui',
                age: 75,
                email: 'aaaa@aaa.com'
            }, {
                name: 'Ana',
                age: 67,
                email: 'aaaa@aaa.com'
            }],
        };
    });        
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if u enter  some values in the table and then do add, it will create a similar row, not an empty one, someone help me plz

Comment: i don't get what is the problem here you clone the first row then you add it to table. do you need a raw in which u can't edit?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3w7h6hLL/ when i click in add, if i have values in first row, it will duplicate information insted of creating a empty row

Comment: @Radu i need to create a empty row, and when i click add with some values in the table, the row added have information, when i want the row with no information

Comment: unfortunately your fiddle is not working at all. I've put your fields into the a simple html and it worked as expected :(

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have the values and you're duplicating row DOM elements.

mixing native javascript and angular et pretty much a bad idea.

Just use an ng-repeat :

```
                             <tr ng-repeat="subject in student.subjects" >
                            <td><input size=25 type="text" ng-model="subject.name" name="latbox"/></td>
                            <td><input size=25 type="text" subject="subject.age" name="lngbox1"/></td>
                            <td><input size=25 type="text" name="lngbox2" /></td>
                            <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" ng-click="deleteRow($index)"/></td>
                            <input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add" ng-click="insRow()"/>
                         </tr>
```

Then in the controller :

```
$scope.insRow = function(){
    $scope.student.subject.push({});//push new empty object this should do the trick
}
  $scope.deleteRow(index)
{
     $scope.student.subject.slice(index,1);// the $index in the html is a vaaraible fron ng-repeat so i can pass it in the js here in order to remove the element. Slice modify the current array, he returns the elements removed.
}
```

When detecting changes, angular will redraw the elements himself.

Note : i change **onclick** by **ng-click**. I changed id by name because you may have element of the same name but you musn't have elements with the same id.

Comment: i tried but can't make fiddle works angular won't find the module even though it declared properly. Just change the <tr> line by mine, and add the javascript code in your studentController